# angular oidc-client-js silent renew is not working with multiple tabs

Tags: oidc-client-js

`In the angular oidc-client-js silent renew is not invoking when application opened new tab and closed pervious logged in tab

http://localhost:4200/silent-renew.html

Following code is using in the silent-renew.html

```
var manager = new Oidc.UserManager();
manager.signinSilentCallback().catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Silent renew should be work on new opened tab, even we have valid token, It is working only for the current tab on which user is logged in.`